# Adding two numbers together should show 1 instead shows 01

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the original value of an href and add a 1 to it, the original value at the moment is 0, but when I add (not append) it shows 01. How can I make this show 1 instead

```
var total_likes = ($("#" + $(event.target).attr('id')+".view_status_likes").text() + 1);
$("#" + $(event.target).attr('id')+".view_status_likes").text(total_likes);
```

I apologise for the short question.

Comment: There are many ways to do it: use `parseInt()` or `Number()`, or do `- 0` or `* 1` before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If JavaScript perceives them as strings, the + sign becomes a concatenation operator.

Try this:

`var total_likes = (parseInt($("#" + $(event.target).attr('id')+".view_status_likes").text(), 10) + 1);`

parseInt converts the String to an int and you should be able to do mathematical operations on the value.

Comment: please add a solution how to convert the string to a number

Comment: You omitted the radix in parseInt.

Comment: provide the second argument to `parseInt`, to avoid octal number conversions: http://fczaja.blogspot.com.br/2010/09/javascript-parseint-gotcha.html

Comment: I've never had an issue with numbers being recognized by octals but I've amended the answer. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a number, and then append:

```
var total_likes = parseInt($("#" + (event.target).attr('id')+".view_status_likes").text(), 10) + 1;
```